# 3x4 keypad only types numbers even when in the letter mode is shown

Tags: text-input

I hope anybody can help me out. Any tips would be very much appreciated!

I changed the keyboard input mode from qwerty to 3x4, as I can't manage the small buttons of qwerty. I realize the 3x4 has a letter mode, a number mode and a symbols mode. I can see the alphabet characters on-screen, but pressing them produces numbers.

*This is me typing 'hello' on the keypad, once with XT9 on and again with it off.*

[image]

To get 'h' I would tap the `ghi` button twice, but it yields '44' instead.

I checked there is a language selected for predictive text. I really want to get this working without installing a third-party keyboard, as I did that before and the nature of my device's low internal memory really makes it difficult.

Running Android 2.3.6, Cyanogenmod Revolution Light build

Comment: What happens when you click the 123 button above the settings button. Does it change to abc?

Comment: If I press the `123` button the letters change to a numeric keypad, 0 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

Where you were enter web or app, what ever use this type of keyboard exclusively just to let you write only number code or phone number. If you will enter other app (writing box) and try to write using the keyboard 3x4 you will be able to write alphabetic characters.